# How many selections contain exactly $4$ green balls and $2$ yellow balls if you pick a subset of $6$ balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question: Given a set of $13$ balls, $9$ of which are green and the other $4$ are yellow, if you pick a subset $6$ balls, how many selections contain exactly $4$ green balls and $2$ yellow balls?

I know that there are $\binom{13}{6}$ ways to pick a subset of 6 balls and that the number of ways to pick exactly $4$ green balls and $2$ yellow balls is equal to the number of ways to pick exactly 4 yellow balls out of 6 picks (since the other two will have to be yellow) and vice versa. Besides that, I have no idea how to solve this problem (though I'm pretty sure the answer is $756$).

Comment: Just select $4$ green balls from the green pile, and $2$ yellow balls from the yellow pile.

Comment: Oh... of course. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Don Thousand said, all I needed to do was select $4$ green balls from the green pile and $2$ yellow balls from the yellow pile.

So $\binom{9}{4}$$\binom{4}{2}$ = $(126)(6) = 756$